# HTML/PHP connected to linux terminal. Changing IP Address of an interface through a submit form in php/html

Tags: javascript, php, html, linux

Im trying to figure out if there is a way to statically change the ip of an interface from simply imputing a new ip address in a submit form, from a page created in php/html.

Trying to create a web page where there will be 2 submit forms , each of them representing the interface of my linux virtual machine. When i type an ip as 10.1.1.10 in that submit form , the ip address of that interface to change.

Thanks!

Comment: Tricky because changing the IP would make the machine lose connection so it might be hard to get a response back to your request.

Comment: Setup a `<form>` to ask for the IP.  The action page takes that address and calls a bash script that does the work (using sudo).  As @ADyson pointed out, this can be problematic, and he did not even mention security, typos, injection of malicious code, ...